# Whitespaces coming in while exporting data from Teradata BTEQ file

Tags: shell, csv, teradata, export-to-csv, ksh

I have a BTEQ script which I'm running from shell (Ksh). **Aim** is to **export** the contents of a Teradata table to a .csv file. **Problem** is while exporting data too many white spaces are being introduced between columns. I have tried
 1. Trimming individual columns
 2. Using Cast to convert each column datatype in Char
but none of this seems to help.
BTEQ code looks something like this (I have used REPORT file since I need file headers.

```
.EXPORT REPORT FILE = exportfilepath.csv;
.SET SEPARATOR ",";
.SET TITLEDASHES OFF;
.set RECORDMODE OFF;
.set width 65531;
.SET ERRORLEVEL 3807 SEVERITY 0

select 
  trim('"' || trim(cast(col1 as char(256))) || '"') AS col1,
  trim('"' || trim(cast(col2 as char(256))) || '"') AS col2,
  trim(cast(col3 as INTEGER)) AS col3,
  trim(cast(col4 as char(6))) AS  col4,
  trim(col5) AS col5,
  trim(cast(col6 as decimal(18,2)) AS col6,
  trim(date) AS date
from table A;
```

Col1 and Col2 are having lot of white spaces between them.Any help as to how I can remove those white spaces. What else can I do in this case? I cannot decrease the char size since these are names with variable sizes.

I have added '"' here because col1 and col2 are names with comma in between them. Since the exported .csv file needs to phrased the format is not proper.

Comment: Kindly include sample data in your question.

Comment: Did not test, perhaps try this: Choose a `.SET SEPARATOR "#"` that's not in your normal output. Remove all spaces around the SEPARATOR. Replace all double quotes with two of them (escaping them in csv format). Put double quotes around all fields (start-of-line, end-of-line and on both sides of the Separator). And replace the sep with the one you want. Something like `sed 's/"/""/g; s/^.*$/"&"/;s/ *# */","/g'`.

Answer (score 1):

`REPORT` format is for printing, i.e. fixed width plus separator.

To generate comma-delimted data without adding seperators and quoting better use `CSV` like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
 ( SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4.col5,col6,current_date as dt
   FROM table A
 )
SELECT str (title '')
FROM TABLE
  (CSV(NEW VARIANT_TYPE(cte.col1,cte.col2,cte.col3
                       ,cte.col4.cte.col5,cte.col6
                       ,cte.dt), ',', '"'
      ) RETURNS (str varchar(32000) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)
  ) AS t1;
```

Or switch to TPT & `DELIMITED` format.